# Laravel whereHas on M2M having same attribute

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have two models, **word** and **meaning**, in a Many-to-Many relationship.

Model Meaning:

```
public function words(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Word::class);
}
```

Model Word:

```
public function meanings(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Meaning::class);
}
```

I need to find all the meanings that have a word equal to their self name. I tried:

```
$meanings = Meaning::whereHas('word', function ($query) { 
               $query->where('meaning.name', 'word.name'); 
            })->get();
```

But this searches meanings that are called literally **"word.name"**. 
Any idea ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a special 'where' for this case, it 's 'whereColumn', this 
where meant to make comparison between two columns:

```
$meanings = Meaning::whereHas('word', function ($query) { 
               $query->whereColumn('meaning.name', 'word.name'); 
            })->get();
```

more details on:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Great! Thank you ;)